# Transfered USDC from Arbitrum Network in Metamask to Phantom Wallet Eth address - I cant access funds

Tags: metamask, wallet-transfer, arbitrum, recover

I transfered USDC from Arbitrum Network in Metamask to Phantom Eth address - I cant access funds.

Does anyone know of a way to recover?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the private key for the phantom address?  What chain is phantom address?

Comment: Yes I have my private key and I sent it to the Eth address in my Phantom wallet, so it will be on the eth chain